# Http session is always created on android version ModernHttpClient(okHttp1.5)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient, okhttp

Note that both platform are using HttpClient code below. However the native message handler change depending on device : Android using OKhttp1.5 and IOS NSurlSession which is handle from ModernHttpClient library.

My problem is on the android device, a session is always created on the server each time a request is called and it shouldn't.

However, on the IOS the session remain before the session timeout reach out which help performance.

Is there something i need to do on the android version specially to retain the session cookie ?

Thanks!

```
private static HttpClient _mobileService = null;
public static HttpClient MobileService
{
    get
    {
        if (_mobileService == null)
        {
            NativeMessageHandler nmh = new NativeMessageHandler();
            _mobileService = new HttpClient(nmh);
        }

        return _mobileService;
    }
    set
    { 
        _mobileService = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you test this: var nmh = new NativeMessageHandler(false, false, new NativeCookieHandler());